# does these battery stats are reasonable for rMBP? (max charge 98% after 25 full cycles)

Tags: battery, macbook-pro

I have my rMBP for 14 months, during the first month I barly used it and it was off most of the time. today I'm connecting it to a display (unfortunately the fonts are blurry!) and the lid is closed most of the time. the power charger is connected most of the time (prevents the computer from sleeping). from time to time I'm openening the lid and disconnect the charger to let the battary drain.

[image: coconutBattary]
[image]

Is it normal that my max charge decreased to 98%?

Thank you.

Comment: your computer should be able to have 1000 cycles before your battery is consumed, however it should be able to keep around 80% carge ability, so, id say your computer is more than fine

Answer (score 1):

Definitely. I had a MacBook Pro for 5 years, and by the end, the battery health was 73%. Yours looks to be 98% after 14 months. Battery degradation is just a fact of owning a laptop and not something to be terribly worried about.

EDIT: Apple support website says this:

Occasionally, the battery may not show a full charge (100%) in OS X, even after the power adapter has been connected for an extended period of time. The battery may appear to stop charging between 93 percent and 99 percent. This behavior is normal and will help to prolong the overall life of the battery.